# How to separate two numbers from string using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, schematron

I have an element in my XML document: `<resolution>1920x1080</resolution>`. I want to get these two numbers from the string using XPath to work with them in Schematron. Is there any option?

Answer (score 1):

Use the XPath expression

```
substring-before(resolution,'x')
```

to get '1920' and

```
substring-after(resolution,'x')
```

to get '1080'.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you are using XSLT2, you can use `tokenize()`, which returns a sequence a strings:

`tokenize(resolution, 'x')`

Results would be:

`tokenize(resolution, 'x')[1]` = '1920'

`tokenize(resolution, 'x')[2]` = '1080'